# Can I change the playback framerate?

Tags: animation

I'm animating a character and would like the ability to change the rate of playback in the editor window so I can get an idea of what the character would look like if played back faster or slower.  Is there a way to do this in Blender 2.9?

Comment: No.  That uses the old blender interface.  Those options are not present in Blender 2.91.

Comment: It's still the same and worth a try: *Printer Icon > Dimensions > Frame Rate*

Comment: Yes, it looks like I can set the option there.

Comment: @kitfox in which case, please accept the suggested duplicate :)